# Prevent AWS glue crawler to create multiple tables

Tags: aws-glue

I created a glue crawler which crawls the data and creates the table in the glue data catalog. Suppose I have a CSV file (`file1.csv`) which has a schema like (`id`,`name`) and once the crawler job execution is completed it creates the Athena table (`crawler_file`) with 2 columns (`id`,`name`). Now there is a new file (`file2.csv`) which has a schema like (`id`,`name`,`roll_no`). Currently when the glue crawler is executing it is creating a new Athena table (`crawler_file_111`) with schema (`id`,`name`,`roll_no`). Can I configure the crawler in such a way that the crawler instead of creating the new table updates the existing schema of the table? In this scenario instead of creating a new Athena table (`crawler_file_111`) it should update the existing Athena table (`crawler_file`). Can I somehow achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Edit Crawler Page, kindly enable the following. This must work for you.

[image]

Comment: Why shouldn't the first option work in this case? Shouldn't it automatically update the schema by adding another column?